# Python Tweepy Unfollow Least Recent

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm working on a Python and Tweepy script to unfollow users who are not following me back. The script below is working, but it unfollows the most recent users that I have followed. I would like it to unfollow the least recent users. I have looked online for a while and have not been able to find anything. Can anyone help me with adding this piece of code to my script? Thanks!

```
import tweepy
import time

def get_twitter_api():
    # personal details
    consumer_key = "consumer_key"
    consumer_secret = "consumer_secret"
    access_token = "access_token"
    access_token_secret = "access_token_secret"

    # authentication of consumer key and secret
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

    # authentication of access token and secret
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    return api

def process():
    interval = 60 * 2
    api = get_twitter_api()

    followers = api.followers_ids(api.me().id)
    print("Followers", len(followers))
    friends = api.friends_ids(api.me().id)
    print("You follow:", len(friends))


    for friend in friends:
        if friend not in followers:
            api.destroy_friendship(friend) 
            time.sleep(interval)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since twitter displays friends list chronologically, those recently followed will be at the top.

So the trick I used is to reverse the friends list as:

```
for friend in friends[::-1]
```

Comment: I tested that and it appears to do exactly what I wanted. I just needed to add a colon at the end. Thanks for the help! I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while.